# Getting user object as null while validating using Next-auth and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I've created the DB using MongoDB as an separate folder called server and another seperate folder is my next application. I want to authenticate the user from the next app with the MongoDB user data. I'm using Next-auth for this. The "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js" code looks like,

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "Username" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "text", placeholder: "Password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          console.log("Connecting to db");
          const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
          });
          console.log("Connected to db");
          const db = client.db("next-auth");
          const user = await db
            .collection("users")
            .findOne({ username: credentials.username });
          console.log(user, "user");

          return null;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Here the db is connecting but the user object is coming as null like below.

```
Connecting to db
Connected to db
null user
```

Any help on this would be appreciated since I'm new to next-auth.

Comment: you mean when you console.log(user, "user") it is `null` ?

Comment: @Hatana Yes it is!

Comment: try `console.log(db, "db")` just before `const user = ...`

Comment: @Hatana I'm getting lot of objects while consoling it. DB name and url are coming in that log.

Answer (score 0):

The object user came null because I mentioned project name instead of db-name. It got fixed now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).